# In Image prediction gives me wrong prediction

Tags: python, neural-network

I want to predict the images are man, girl, animal so I am trying to classify them when I tried for one image like only girl it will gives me right output that it is girl but when I try more than one input image just like men, girl, animal it's automatically classify all the image as men because my first image is men. but when I go for animal, girl, men then it will predict all the image as animal why ?

Code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import  Convolution2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense




from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator



classifier = Sequential()

classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(64, 64, 3), activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))




classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

classifier.add(Flatten())

classifier.add(Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))




classifier.add(Dense(units=4, activation='softmax'))

#classifier.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))

classifier.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                   shear_range=0.3,
                                   zoom_range=0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip=True)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('data_set/traning',
                                                 target_size=(64, 64),
                                                 batch_size=32,
                                                 class_mode='categorical'
                                                )

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('data_set/testing',
                                                 target_size=(64, 64),
                                                 batch_size=32,
                                                 class_mode='categorical')


classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                         steps_per_epoch=244,
                         epochs=30,
                         validation_data=test_set,
                         validation_steps=70)
classifier.save('D:\Registration_form\Image_recognizer\Image_recognizer\dataset2.h5')
print("done")
```

Comment: It cant be decided by simple code shown,  model performance depends on many other parameters of data, training, optimizers, please ensure parameters proper and check one by one

Comment: Maybe you are doing something wrong with your predictions. Could you share the code where your model does the predictions? You have only posted the training part.

Comment: img in images:
            for i in range(1):
                test_image = cv2.imread(path + "/" + mypiclist[i])
                inimg = cv2.imread(path + "/" + mypiclist[i])
                test = cv2.resize(test_image, (64, 64))

                test_image = image.img_to_array(test)

                test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=0)

                modules = tf.keras.models.load_model("Image_recognizer\dataset2.h5")
                result = modules.predict(test_image)

Comment: Why this: ```for i in range(1)```?